# Tracking referrals across sub domain

Tags: google-analytics

I have set up Google analytics on my root domain and all subdomains. I have a couple of goals set up and data is flowing into Google Analytics. I have a root domain (landing pages) and a subdomain for the service I'm selling. When going to Conversions > Goals > Overview in Google Analytics, my subdomain shows my root domain as the source and referral of all conversions. This makes sense since there is a link to sign up from my root domain to a signup page om my subdomain. But I would rather see the actual source/medium of the visitor coming to my root domain.

All domains log to the same UA property and I have set up a number of views to see data from the individual domains. GA is configured through Google Tag Manager as shown here:

[image]

Any idea to how to set this up?

Comment: Would appreciate a comment if people downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with cross-domain tracking in GA. The main domain was not added to the exclusion list and that caused referrals to subdomains show up in the referral list. To solve it, just add the main domain to the exclusion list in the ga property.

The referral exclusion list is found under ADMIN > ACCOUNT > PROPERTY> TRACKING INFO > REFERRAL EXCLUSION LIST
[image]

Comment: Both domains are on the same property.

Comment: can you add in how you've implemented GA on both sites? Paste the code that's used.

Comment: Both domains add the same Google tag manager script. GA is set up in tag manager using the built in GA feature.

Comment: Are there any customizations to the GA tag in GTM? If so please paste a screenshot.